# Pageview all of sudden not working

Tags: pages, views

I am not sure how to explain it.

MY page view count is not working all of sudden.

Here is my code:

```
$output .= '<div class="mainpageview fa fa-eye">';
    $views = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pageview', true );
        if ( !$views ) 
            $output .= __( '0 page view' );

        if ( $views == 1 )
            $output .= __( '1 page view' );

        if ( $views > 1 )
               $output .= sprintf(__( ' %s page view' ), $views);

$output .= '</div>';
```

It worked just fine till last night then all of sudden, it just shows `0 page view`

Comment: You should check that `$post->ID` is correct. Can you show us the contextwhwere you are using that code and where `$post` comes from?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you elaborate how I can check that $post->ID is correct?

Comment: Just check the value of the variable (you can use `echo`, `var_dump`, `print_r`, etc) to see if it is what it should be, that is, the correct post ID from which you want to get the `pageview` meta field. If it is correct, you should check that the meta field `pageview` exists. Your code seems OK, doing those checks is the only advise I can give you with the given information.

Comment: It seems like something stuffed up your `$post` global. Are you using custom queries or `query_posts` for that matter anywhere in page template or any function in a template that is using the before mentioned

Comment: So little update, I used Plugin organizer to organize plugins. When I deactivated it, it worked fine now :) Thanks!